# Series Length Calculation

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I want to calculate the number of terms in the series given by the below algorithm:

```
if n=1 STOP:    
    if n is odd then n=3n+1 
    else n=n/2
```

For example, if n is 22 the series would be as below and the length of the series would be 16:

```
22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

I came up with the below recursive function in python:

```
class CycleSizeCalculator(object):
    '''
    Class to calculate the cycle count of a number. Contains the following
    members:
    counter - holds the cycle count
    number  - input number value
    calculate_cycle_size() - calculates the cycle count of the number given
    get_cycle_length()     - returns the cycle count
    '''
    def calculate_cycle_size(self,number):
        """
        Calculates the cycle count for a number passed
        """
        self.counter+=1# count increments for each recursion
        if number!=1:
            if number%2==0:
                self.calculate_cycle_size((number/2))
            else:
                self.calculate_cycle_size((3*number)+1)

    def __init__(self,number):
        '''
        variable initialization
        '''
        self.counter = 0
        self.number = number
        self.calculate_cycle_size(number)

    def get_cycle_length(self):
        """
        Returns the current counter value
        """
        return self.counter

if __name__=='__main__':
    c = CycleSizeCalculator(22);
    print c.get_cycle_length()
```

This works in most cases but fails with the message Maximum Recursion depth reached for some values of n. Is there an alternate approach to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sequence can be arbitrarily large for some numbers. So a recursive approach may not be enough. You can simply try the iterative approach:

```
def calculate_cycle_size(self,number):
    self.counter = 1
    while number != 1:
        if number%2 == 0:
            number = number / 2
        else:
            number = 3 * number + 1
        self.counter += 1
```

Comment: The sequence isn't even guaranteed to be finite, so even a loop can't promise anything.

Comment: @pjs Yes, but at least the iterative approach can find the length in the cases where the recursion will cause a stack overflow. And I heard that no number has still been found for which the sequence will go forever.

Answer (score 5):

That's the [Collatz Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), and last I heard it remains unproven that it converges to 1 for all positive integer starting points.  Unless you can prove convergence, it's going to be hard to determine what the sequence length will be.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it recursively, this works:

```
def get_count(n):
    return 1 if n == 1 else 1 + get_count(3*n+1 if n%2 else n/2)
```

And an iterative version:

```
def get_count(n):
    i = 1
    while n != 1:
        (n, i) = (3*n+1 if n%2 else n/2, i + 1)
    return i
```

Comment: Well, because that's just `return 1`? ;^)

Comment: @bcorso This has the same problem as the code above. The function is still recursive and prone to stack overflow.

Comment: @0605002 true, but it might be useful if the OP knows that his 50 lines of code could have been 2 lines.